# Flatten a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making the steamroller bonfire in freeCodeCamp
I can't figure out why my code is not working 
and it only goes for the first element in an array

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    // I'm a steamroller, baby


    var flat = [];

    for( i=0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
        if( Array.isArray(arr[i]) ){
           flat = flat.concat(steamrollArray(arr[i]));
        } else {
            flat.push(arr[i]);
        }
    } // end of the for loop


    return flat;
}
```

Comment: Can the array be arbitrary deep nested?

Comment: yes it can !
why ?

Comment: `var i = 0`. [Without `var`, `i` is a global variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it), so every call to `steamrollArray` shares it and modifies it.

Comment: What about feeding the `streamrollArray` a scalar object like a float,etc. so nesting depth `0`?

Comment: You are allocating too much useless arrays.

Comment: how is that ?
can you explain

Answer (score 1):

Side effects, ES6, you can achieve a deep flatten in an iterative pattern using `.splice`

```
function flatten(arr) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) arr.splice(i, 1, ...arr[i]);
        else ++i;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

e.g. usage

```
flatten([1, [2], [[3]], [4, [5, [6]]], [[[7], 8], 9]]);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

If you don't want side effects, `.slice` before,

```
functon flatClone(arr) {
    return flatten(arr.splice());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As is commented by [@Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811776/flatten-a-nested-array#comment61196451_36811776) the problem is that you use a counter `i` which is not declared in the function and thus global. As a result recursive calls will alter the `i` of the caller, etc.

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    // I'm a steamroller, baby
    var flat = [];

    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
        if( Array.isArray(arr[i]) ){
           flat = flat.concat(steamrollArray(arr[i]));
        } else {
            flat.push(arr[i]);
        }
    } // end of the for loop
    return flat;
}
```

---

A second challenge however is making the code more efficient in both time and memory. This can be done by limiting the amount of list construction to one. You can do this by using a concept called an *accumulator*: a variable you update through the recursive process. First we need to initialize the variable:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  return steamer(arr,[]);
}
```

In this case the accumulator is the result as well, and we initialize the result as an empty array. Evidently we still need to implement the `steamer` function:

```
function steamer (arr,target) {
  if(Array.isArray(arr)) {
    var n = arr.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      steamer(arr[i],target);
    }
  } else {
    target.push(arr);
  }
  return target;
}
```

What one does is passing the target through the recursive enumeration of the array tree. In case the value turns out to be a scalar (`Array.isArray` returns `false`) we add the element to the end of the `target`; otherwise we perform a recursive call.

The last thing this function does is returning the `target`, after the initial `steamer` call, `target` will be filled with all elements in the nested list.

The advantage is we do not need expensive `concat` functions, but only use the `push` function *O(n)* times. If we make abstraction of the processing time necessary to construct an array (assume `push` works in O(1) time), the algorithm now works in *O(n)* time and memory with *n* the number of leaves in the list tree.

Answer (score 0):

try recurse the array in the following method, use res[] to save the result;

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var res=[];
  function recurse(array)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
      if(!Array.isArray(array[i]))
        res.push(array[i]);
      else 
        recurse(array[i]);
    }
  }
  recurse(arr);
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function steamrollArray(arr) { 
   return String(arr).split(',').map(Number); }
```

If it works in all your cases, it works for the "flatten" example above, let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code,hope this helpful:

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  let newArr = [];

  //function:push every value in arr to newArr;
  const getValue = function(elem) {
    if(Array.isArray(elem)) {
      elem.forEach(getValue);
    }else{
      newArr.push(elem);
    }
  }

  arr.forEach(getValue);
  console.log(newArr);
  return newArr;
}

steamrollArray([[["a"]], [["b"]]]);
```